# Identify if an Android Activity/Application is using OpenGL or not

Tags: android, reflection, opengl-es

I'm trying to figure out a way to find if a certain activity is using GLSurfaceView as content view or not.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
    // as the ContentView for this Activity.
    GLSurfaceView glView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLView);
}
```

I already tried to check the class type of the activity's root view without any luck.
Open to any idea, including reflection.

Comment: Is the activity in question part of your own application? Or are you trying to also make this work for activities in other applications/processes?

Comment: Hi @RetoKoradi! Yes its in my own application (process) but it is a part of an SDK so I don't have access to the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. It turns out that the GLSurfaceView use its own rendering thread. Just check if the thread is GLThread (not the usual main looper).